# How to add/remove a div on button click in react js

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Trying to add a div based on its id in react js.I have below react div element

```
<div id="section1">
        <table><tr><td><h3>Section1</h3></td></tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
            <li><label> input1 : </label><input type="text" size="100" name="input1" onChange={this.onChange} /></li>
            <li><label> input2 : </label><input type="text" size="100" name="input2" onChange={this.onChange}  /></li>
            <li><label> input3 : </label><input type="text" size="100" name="input3" onChange={this.onChange}/></li>
            </td>
          </tr></table>
          </div>
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Can you give us a little more information on how you're rendering it?

Comment: @samuei this is just a input form with few fields , i will have + and - to add or remove same form in my page.is there any way i can handle using the div id in react component?

Comment: It would probably be better to handle that prior to rendering, but it's hard to say without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

```js
function removeElement(elementId) {
2.    // Removes an element from the document.
3. var element = document. getElementById(elementId);
4. element. parentNode. removeChild(element);
5. }
```

Comment: This is not a solution with React.